# Substitue extra double quotes in a single CSV fields via bash

Tags: python, bash, csv

I need to substitute extra double quotes from CSV log files (fields are comma separated and quoted by double-quotes). The substitution must impact only the last field of CSV.

Input log file example:

```
"24-12-2015","23:07:08","00","01","00","00","START","00","END","JS786JGDG7899JSGJHG"dsdajasghsahd"
```

Expected output:

```
"24-12-2015","23:07:08","00","01","00","00","START","00","END","JS786JGDG7899JSGJHG''dsdajasghsahd"
```

I need to complete this task in bash or python.

Comment: You should describe what you have tried so far in order to get some help.

Comment: Why use both `python` and `bash` tags?

Comment: This is my first post and I used suggested tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk "{gsub(/'/, \"''\", \$NF)} 1" file.csv

"24-12-2015","23:07:08","00","01","00","00","START","00","END","JS786JGDG7899JSGJHG''dsdajasghsahd"
```

Comment: Are you serious? Most of the these reps aren't even counted as I cross daily limit. Many a times a problem might appear trivial to experts but it is not that simple for posters.

Comment: It isn't that it's trivial, the question is awful, it's just asking for code and doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Thanx for your help anubhava. Really appreciated and useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{gsub(/\"/,"\47\47",$NF)gsub(/^\47\47/,"\"",$NF);gsub(/\047\047$/,"\"",$NF) }1' file

"24-12-2015","23:07:08","00","01","00","00","START","00","END","JS786JGDG7899JSGJHG''dsdajasghsahd"
```

Comment: It works with the single line used as sample, but when run against entire logs, it replace also the last double quotes used as field terminator. The end of the line is converted from "\r\n to ''\r\n